# Socket Hangup Error in Node.js on using https

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, http-post

I'm trying to use HTTP GET method via Nodejs using secure connection https. Here is my code:

```
var https = require('https');
https.globalAgent.options.secureProtocol = 'SSLv3_method';

var options = {
  host: 'my_proxy_address',
  port: 3128,
  path: 'https://birra-io2014.appspot.com/_ah/api/birra/v1/beer',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    accept: '*/*'
  }
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
  res.on('data', function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});
req.end();

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

When i run this, i get an error:

```
{ [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET', sslError: undefined }
```

I cannot use HTTP because appspot requires https.
Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "socket hang up" means the server you're contacting never sent a response ?

Comment: Is there any error log by `req.on('error' .... console.log(e);`?

Comment: @adeneo but when i post this url `"https://birra-io2014.appspot.com/_ah/api/birra/v1/beer"` i get all my content. I did this using curl as well and it worked, why is it not working with node.js.

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni - well i posted the error, either you do console.log or console.error, it gives the same thing.

Comment: @user3275261 Well, I checked and changed code of yours and its working for, I have put same code in my answer. Please let me know if it didn't work for you too. I have changed `port`, `host` & `path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code. (Its working for me)

```
var https = require('https');

var options = {
  port: 443,
  host: 'birra-io2014.appspot.com',
  path: '/_ah/api/birra/v1/beer',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    accept: '*/*'
  }
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

  res.on('data', function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});
req.end();

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error('ERROR object ==>' + e);
});
```

Comment: it gives:
    `ERROR object ==>Error: connect ETIMEDOUT`

Comment: I think you are behind a proxy server. since you mentioned `host: 'my_proxy_address'`